# How to sum positive and negative values

Tags: sql-server

I wrote a query to get the results I need. Now I need from that result to subtract the negative values from the positive values based on the grouping of some other columns.

**My query:**

```
Select ISNULL(SUM(QTYH),0) as QTY, 
ISNULL(SUM(AMTH),0)as AMT, 
PART_NBR, A_NBR, DATE 
From (
    Select PART_NBR, 
           R.A_NBR,  
        Case 
         when PO_DEBIT_CREDIT = 'H' 
         then - QTY else QTY  
         end as QTYH, 
        Case   
         when PO_DEBIT_CREDIT='H' 
         then -AMT else AMT 
         end as AMTH, 
         DATEPART(yyyy,R.DATE) as DATE, 
         PO_DEBIT_CREDIT

    FROM Receipts as R,Master as M,Vendors as t                
    WHERE R.A_NBR = 'A-10' 
    AND CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,R.DATE)as varchar) >= '2013' 
    AND CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,R.DATE)as varchar) <= '2013' 
    AND R.A_NBR = M.A_NBR 
    GROUP BY PART_NBR, 
             R.A_NBR, 
             DATEPART(yyyy,R.DATE), PO_DEBIT_CREDIT,QTY,AMT) as tb1
Group by PART_NBR, A_NBR, DATE,  PO_DEBIT_CREDIT
```

**Results:**

```
QTY  AMT        PART_NBR  A_NBR  Date 
=====================================   
-1   -11208.58  101       A-10   2013   
 8   89668.64   101       A-10   2013   
 3   46362.42   102       A-10   2013
```

I wish to group the rows together based on the last 3 columns: `PART_NBR, A_NBR,  Date`, and have the values on the first 2 columns added together based on that grouping.

**Desired output**:

```
QTY  AMT        PART_NBR  A_NBR  Date       
 7   78460.06   101       A-10   2013   
 3   46362.42   102       A-10   2013
```

Comment: Is this MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: a sample of the source table would be helpfull

Comment: Just don't group by QTY or AMT then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your query in a subquery and perform some grouping and aggregation on it:

```
SELECT SUM(QTY) AS QTY, SUM(AMT) AS AMT, PART_NBR, A_NBR, [Date]
FROM
(SELECT.... YOUR EXISTING QUERY HERE)
GROUP BY PART_NBR, A_NBR, [Date]
```

This will group by the last 3 columns: `PART_NBR, A_NBR, [Date]` and add the values in the first 2 columns per group, thus adding the positive values ot the negative values.

Here's an example taking the results from your query output, wrapped in a subquery:

```
CREATE TABLE #YourSubquery
    ([QTY] int, [AMT] DECIMAL(10,2), [PART_NBR] int, [A_NBR] varchar(4), [Date] int)
;

INSERT INTO #YourSubquery
    ([QTY], [AMT], [PART_NBR], [A_NBR], [Date])
VALUES
    (-1, -11208.58, 101, 'A-10', 2013),
    (8, 89668.64, 101, 'A-10', 2013),
    (3, 46362.42, 102, 'A-10', 2013)
;

SELECT SUM(QTY) AS QTY, SUM(AMT) AS AMT, PART_NBR, A_NBR, [Date]
FROM
(SELECT * FROM #YourSubquery) t
GROUP BY PART_NBR, A_NBR, [Date]

DROP TABLE #YourSubquery
```

**Output:**

```
QTY AMT         PART_NBR    A_NBR   Date
========================================
7   78460.06    101         A-10    2013
3   46362.42    102         A-10    2013
```

**Caveat**: this is based on the assumption your `AMT` column is a numeric data type, as your output is showing a `$` sign.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a solution

```
Select ISNULL(SUM(QTYH),0) as QTY, ISNULL(SUM(AMTH),0)as AMT, PART_NBR, A_NBR, DATE From (
Select PART_NBR, R.A_NBR,  Case when PO_DEBIT_CREDIT = 'H' then - QTY else QTY  end as QTYH, Case   when PO_DEBIT_CREDIT='H' then -AMT else AMT end as AMTH, DATEPART(yyyy,R.DATE) as DATE, PO_DEBIT_CREDIT

FROM Receipts as R,Master as M,Vendors as t                
WHERE R.A_NBR = 'A-10' AND CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,R.DATE)as varchar) >= '2013' AND CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,R.DATE)as varchar) <= '2013' AND R.A_NBR = M.A_NBR 
GROUP BY PART_NBR, R.A_NBR, DATEPART(yyyy,R.DATE), PO_DEBIT_CREDIT,QTY,AMT) as tb1
Group by PART_NBR, A_NBR, DATE,  PO_DEBIT_CREDIT
Having ISNULL(SUM(QTYH),0) >= 0
```

Comment: Thanks but this one only remove the negative one.

Answer (score 0):

In the outer select you don't need to group using PO_DEBIT_CREDIT.
The outer group by should be

`"Group by PART_NBR, A_NBR, DATE"` instead of `"Group by PART_NBR, A_NBR, DATE,  PO_DEBIT_CREDIT"`

So the modified query is:

```
Select ISNULL(SUM(QTYH),0) as QTY, ISNULL(SUM(AMTH),0) as AMT, PART_NBR, A_NBR, DATE 
From (
Select PART_NBR, R.A_NBR,  Case when PO_DEBIT_CREDIT = 'H' then - QTY else QTY  end as QTYH, Case   when PO_DEBIT_CREDIT='H' then -AMT else AMT end as AMTH, DATEPART(yyyy,R.DATE) as DATE, PO_DEBIT_CREDIT

FROM Receipts as R,Master as M,Vendors as t                
WHERE R.A_NBR = 'A-10' AND CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,R.DATE)as varchar) >= '2013' AND CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,R.DATE)as varchar) <= '2013' AND R.A_NBR = M.A_NBR 
GROUP BY PART_NBR, R.A_NBR, DATEPART(yyyy,R.DATE), PO_DEBIT_CREDIT,QTY,AMT) as tb1
Group by PART_NBR, A_NBR, DATE
```